# Problems outputting a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**What I have**

I have an array looking like this:

[image: Multidimensional Array]

**What I want**

What I want is a table like this:

[image: Array Output table]

The result should be a table where every item is listed in the table and all it's child arrays following.

But my table is looking like this at the moment:

[image: False table result]

The problem is that as an example item 1 is outputted multiple times.

I don't understand why my array is getting outputted like this. It doesn't just take the first item and outputs every payment array in it and then takes the next item and so on.

**The code**

This is my foreach code snippet

```php
foreach ($paidgift as $item => $payments) {
    echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$item.'</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>';
    foreach ($payments as $paymentdetail) {
        echo'<tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>'.$paymentdetail['paid'].'</td>
                <td>'.$paymentdetail['nname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$paymentdetail['vname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$paymentdetail['mail'].'</td>
             </tr>';
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Thanks in advance for any help**

Comment: Looks pretty good to me, any other code you missed to post?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It made me find the problem. I will answer my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by myself as I went trough my code to see that I surely haven't forgotten something.

I was a real idiot. The problem was, that I coded my foreach code right into the while loop of my "array creation" script. So every time I'm creating a new array entry it outputs everything.

My bad!

**Works great now with the foreach loop outside my while loop.**